# Integrating with respect to surface measure

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, surface-integrals

How does one integrate with respect to a surface measure, is it the same as a surface integral? I've tried a google search but couldn't find much.

In particular I have the following problem but can't begin as i don't know the above!

Let $\Gamma \in L^{1}(S^{n-1})$ where $S^{n-1}$ is the (n-1) dimensional sphere on $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$ Given $z \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash \{0\}$ the projection onto $S^{n-1}$ is given by:
$$ z' = \frac{z}{|z|} \in S^{n-1}$$

We define the operator $$Tf(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{|z| > \epsilon}\frac{\Gamma(z')}{|z|^{n}}f(x-z)dz.$$

Show that the limit above exists for $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ i.e. a Schwartz function by assuming that $\int_{S^{n-1}}\Gamma(z')d \sigma(z')=0$ where $d \sigma$ denotes the surface measure on $S^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look in Stein's *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions* from 1970, in Chapter II, Section 4.2., Theorem 3.

To answer your initial question while being a bit nitpicky, it is epistemologically very strange to say that "surface measure" is the same as "surface integral". As you probably learned in a measure theory course, measures are set functions (they take as input sets), whereas the integral (which has to be defined with respect to a measure) can be regarded as a linear operator defined on various function spaces.

However, I guess that your **question** is rather: "Is computing some integral with respect to surface measure the same as computing surface integrals in calculus?". In this case, the answer is **yes**.

For instance, if you have two space dimensions and take $\Gamma(x,y)=\max\{x,0\}$ for $(x,y)\in S^1$, i.e., $x^2+y^2=1$, then you can just use polar coordinates on the circle. If I'm not mistaken, the integral $\mathrm{d}\sigma$ equals 2 in this case.